# select and echo a single field from mysql db using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to select the title column from a particular row

```
$eventid = $_GET['id'];
$field = $_GET['field'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT $field FROM `events` WHERE `id` = '$eventid' ");
echo $result;
```

all i get is `Resource id #19`

How should i do this? What is best method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$eventid = $_GET['id'];
$field = $_GET['field'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT $field FROM `events` WHERE `id` = '$eventid' ");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[$field];
```

but beware of sql injection cause you are using $_GET directly in a query. The danger of injection is particularly bad because there's no database function to escape identifiers. Instead, you need to pass the field through a whitelist or (better still) use a different name externally than the column name and map the external names to column names. Invalid external names would result in an error.

Comment: Or use prepared statements to help avoid SQL Injection. Note: mysql_query is being deprecated, use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: @TimoHuovinen +1 [mysql_query deprecated official link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
echo mysql_result($result, 0);
```

This is enough because you are only fetching one field of one row.

Comment: `mysql_result($result, 0)` for the first (and only) row.

Comment: True. Edited it. But shouldn't this usually work for the first row if I don't explicitly state it.

Comment: @Franz Nope, the second argument is not optional, cf. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

Answer (score 4):

Read the manual, it covers it very well: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Usually you do something like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo $row['firstname'];
  echo $row['lastname'];
  echo $row['address'];
  echo $row['age'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And escape your values with mysql_real_escape_string since PHP6 won't do that for you anymore! :)