# MYSQL - how to select a particular column name

Tags: mysql

This is a really basic mysql question but I rarely work with mysql so here it is.
I understand the basics of selecting particular rows in a table. Here is my statement

```
"SELECT * FROM realForeclosure WHERE auctionDate BETWEEN '2014-12-08' AND '2014-12-09' "
```

But this returns all of the columns for the selected rows. For this particular query I only need one column 'AUCTION_ITEM', How can I return only that data for the selection above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I just SELECT one column in MYSQL instead of all, to make it faster?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404194/can-i-just-select-one-column-in-mysql-instead-of-all-to-make-it-faster)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `*` by the list of your columns:

```
SELECT `AUCTION_ITEM` FROM realForeclosure WHERE auctionDate BETWEEN '2014-12-08' AND '2014-12-09'
```

You could have just found this in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM realForeclosure WHERE auctionDate BETWEEN '2014-12-08' AND '2014-12-09' "
```

Comment: OP wants to select one column, not one row. You're still selecting all columns.